# How to set an image to the button using the other application package name?

Tags: java, android, widget

Im facing a problem as below stated.

I'm having a single button on the widget.On click of the button it open other application.Now my question is how to assign that open application image to my button which is in the widget.
Please help me.

This is my Main class.

```
{

    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
    import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.RemoteViews;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class WidgetMainProvider extends  AppWidgetProvider {
    //  Activity a=new Activity();

        public static String GET_ACTION = "Get_Action";

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);

            if (GET_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "onReceiver()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
            final int N = appWidgetIds.length;


            Log.i("ExampleWidget",  "Updating widgets " + Arrays.asList(appWidgetIds));

            // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
            // provider
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
                //Which defines the UI of Widget
                // initializing widget layout
                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget1);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetOneActivity.class);
               // intent.setAction(GET_ACTION);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
                remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button,pendingIntent);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);

            }}}
```

This is my another class where i have declared the package name,based on that it will open the application.

```
package com.purvotara.example.widget;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class WidgetOneActivity extends Activity {

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */



     @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         PackageInfo pkgInfo=new PackageInfo();
         context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(pkgInfo.packageName);
         Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.drdo.s.a.m.s");       
         startActivity(LaunchIntent);     

          }


    }
```

And also please help me where to put the code which which will set image to the button dynamically.

Here is my Android. manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.eightbitcloud.example.widget"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.purvotara.example.widget.WidgetOneActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <receiver
                android:name="com.purvotara.example.widget.WidgetMainProvider"
                android:label="@string/widget1name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@XML/widget1_info" />
            </receiver> 
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Please help me geeks,im waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you are trying to assign another app icon to your widget button. You can try:

```
PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
Drawable icon = packageManager .getApplicationIcon("com.example.yourapp");
button.setBackgroundDrawable(icon);
```

or

```
Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.example.yourapp");
button.setBackgroundDrawable(icon);
```

I added the following in the WidgetOneActivity class:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 Button button = null;

//YOU NEED TO INITIALIZE YOUR BUTTON HERE, YOUR BUTTON IS NULL
try {
    Drawable icon;
    icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.drdo.s.a.m.s");
    button.setBackground(icon);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.drdo.s.a.m.s");        
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);     

        }
    });

  }
```

After adding this my app is closing.